# plain libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException error

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I was toying around with my projects and separate them into three targets, with separate (and also shared) storyboards and viewcontrollers. I wasn't tried to run at all in the process. Now I tried to run, and the app crashes on load (Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT) with the console only giving this message:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

That's it. Nothing else. I don't even have any function stack call in the Debug navigator. It's just 0 pthread kill, along with 12 UIApplication Main, 13 main, and 14 start. The app doesn't even run the first line of code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function on `AppDelegate`.

Some of the other answers regarding this mostly refer to a "shadow connection", a connection from the storyboard to a non existent outlet in the viewcontrollers. I have verify most of the viewcontrollers and see no such problems. Can anybody help regarding this matter?

Updates:

- removing all the storyboards doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I create a new project, copy all the previous project's resources, set everything up again, and voila, it works!